# how to get an event whenever the network cable is connected or disconnected

Tags: c#

im doing an application in which im transfering file through FTP.i succesfully done all
the things to transfer files and folders.now i want to know how to get an event whenever the
the network cable is connected or disconnected while im transfering a file.

im using SYSTEM.NET NAMESPACE,FTPWEBREQUEST Class.

when will the event get raised i just run mi program and disconnected the network cable
but nothing happens.

im not able to raise the event will u send ur code .actually it is working in vb.net.it doesnt get raised in c# below is mycode:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static event NetworkAvailabilityChangedEventHandler networkchanged;
    string file_to_upload;
    string serverip;
    string username;
    string password;
    FileStream fstream;
    Stream strem;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        networkchanged += new NetworkAvailabilityChangedEventHandler(Form1_networkchanged);


    }

    void Form1_networkchanged(object sender, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e)
    {
        //my implementations goes here
        //throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
```

i done it this is very useful.thank you very much

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.networkavailabilitychanged.aspx) event.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to handled the "network cable is disconnected" case. The FTP library you are using *should*/would time-out or give an error.  What library/class are you using?