# Be informed when a network cable is plugged in / Wifi connected

Tags: c#, .net, networking, network-programming, network-connection

I'm implementing in C# a discovery protocol (DNS-SD). I've a small problem: when my program is running, I need to detect when a new connection is established (network cable plugged or wifi joined), to announce myself on those network too.

But how to detect this? I've seen some code to get the current state of a network card, but no event, and I want to avoid to make some polling on the network cards states.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387650/how-to-get-an-event-whenever-the-network-cable-is-connected-or-disconnected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`GetIstNetworkAvailable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable.aspx)-method to check if there is a network connection at all. Whenever it changes the [`NetworkAvailabilityChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.networkavailabilitychanged.aspx) event get's fired. For more information see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520347/c-sharp-how-do-i-check-for-a-network-connection).

If you want to track the availability of different [`NetworkInterfaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k056bfdz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is an sample on how to do this.

Comment: I may have misunderstood but I believe the OP needs more information than that - eg Connect LAN (event raised), Connect Wifi (silent?) disconnect LAN (silent?), disconnect Wifi (event).

Comment: The NetworkAvailabilityChanged-Event should be raised whenever one of the available networkinterfaces availability changes. You can then test which networkinterfaces are available. I've updated the answer ;)

Comment: Hi, I think that with your last example, I could make what I need

Comment: @Aschratt +1 nice addition